# ListView Data template binding in Xamarin forms

Tags: listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms, datatemplate

I have been trying to populate the data template inside the listview but it does not display anything. My code below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
         x:Class="BlueDemo.ScoreDisplay">
<ContentPage.Content>                 
       <StackLayout> 
        <ListView x:Name="listView" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
           <ListView.ItemTemplate>
           <DataTemplate>
              <ViewCell>
                <Grid>
                  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                     <ColumnDefinition Width="0.7*"/> 
                     <ColumnDefinition Width="0.3*"/> 
                  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>     
                  <Label Text="{Binding name}" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                  <Label Text="{Binding score}" Grid.Column ="1"/>                
                </Grid>
              </ViewCell>
          </DataTemplate>
          </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

```
public partial class ScoreDisplay : ContentPage
{
    public static List<int> Score = new List<int>();
    public static List<string> Name = new List<string>();
     public string[] nme = new string[10];

    public static int[] scr = new int[10];

    public ObservableCollection<Data> mySource{get;set;}
    public ScoreDisplay()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = this;


        nme = Name.ToArray();
        scr=Score.ToArray();

        mySource = new ObservableCollection<Data>();
        for(int i=0;i<nScore.Count;i++)
        {
            mySource.Add(nnew Data {name = nme[i], score = 
            scr[i].ToString()});
        }
        listView.ItemsSource = mySource;
    }  
}

public class Data
{
   public string name { get; set; }
   public string score { get; set; } 
}
```

I have two lists (**Name and Score**) that are getting the value from other page. I am not sure how to bind each and every value in them with Name and Score of listview. 
**EDIT: Working code**

Comment: Hey,does it work?

Comment: I haven't tried yet. Something else came up. Will let you know as soon as I am done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Cause:**

Label.Text is a string .But in your class `Data`,the property name is a `List`.

**Solution:**

Refer the following code.

```
public class Data
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string score { get; set; }
}

public ObservableCollection<Data> mySource { get; set; }

List<int> ScoreList = new List<int>();
List<string> NameList = new List<string>();    

public ScoreDisplay ()
{
  InitializeComponent();

  BindingContext = this;

  NameList.Add("jack");
   // or you can set the list with  the other part of the app

  ScoreList.Add(60);
   //...

  mySource = new ObservableCollection<Data>();

  for (int i=0;i<ScoreList.Count;i++)
   {
      mySource.Add(new Data { name = NameList[i], score = ScoreList[i].ToString()});
   }


  listView.ItemsSource = mySource;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you missed the ItemSource to bind in ListView xaml. Add this line instead of

```
<ListView x:Name="listView" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
```

to

```
<ListView x:Name="listView" ItemsSource="{Binding DataDisplay}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
```

Comment: Hi @Prashanth, its there in the cs part.

Comment: but you need to initialize in Xaml also. It is a collection which bind a property under key values. Try this one

Comment: Check your name and score has values or null in DataDisplay

Comment: It works when I initialize name and score through array. Changing the list to Array and then new Data{ name= Name[0], score = Score[0]} but thats not the approach I want to follow as the list will always change in number.

Comment: From where you pass the data to name. You create using ObservableCollection<Data>.

Comment: Its on the other page where I am taking values form the database and then putting it in a list and then that data in the list is passed to this "public static List<string> Name = new List<string>();" Now if I change this Name list toArray and then populate "public List<string> name { get; set; }" one by one it works. I have to change name list to string name but.

Comment: For this create a Model class for values which you taking from Database, when you call the page set the constructor for same model. So here you get all the datas from database and just load it

Comment: Ok. I will give it a try.

Comment: wait i will update my answer, using model class from database access

Answer (score 0):

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    List<ScoreModel> ScoreList = new List<ScoreModel>();
    List<NameModel> NameList = new List<NameModel>();
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        NameList.Add(new NameModel { Name = "Name1", Id = 0 });
        NameList.Add(new NameModel { Name = "Name2", Id = 1 });

        ScoreList.Add(new ScoreModel { Id = 0, Score = 1 });
        ScoreList.Add(new ScoreModel { Id = 1, Score = 2 });

        var DataDisplay = new List<Data>();

        foreach (var item in NameList)
        {
            foreach (var item1 in ScoreList)
            {
                if(item.Id==item1.Id)
                {
                    DataDisplay.Add(new Data { name = item.Name, score = item1.Score });
                }
            }
        }
        listView.ItemsSource = DataDisplay;
    }
}
public class Data
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int score { get; set; }
}
public class NameModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
public class ScoreModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Score  { get; set; }
}
```

Your xaml:

```
<StackLayout>
    <ListView x:Name="listView">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.7*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.3*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <Label Text="{Binding name}" Grid.Column="0"
                               FontAttributes="Bold" />
                        <Label Text="{Binding score}"
                               Grid.Column="1" />
                    </Grid>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</StackLayout>
```

Hope this may solve your issue.